# Apply a class to every occurrence of character of an element in website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am managing to design a Japanese website where every occurrence of kanji character is enlarged like this [(taken from here)](https://lyrics.imicomweb.com/):

[image: only kanji letters are large]

The site has a script to do this:

```js
const re_kanji = /([\u4E00-\u9FFF])/gi; /* [sic] */
function enlarge_every_occurrence_of_kanji() {
    for ( p of document.getElementsByTagName("p") ) {
        p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll(re_kanji, "<font class=larger-font>$&</font>");
    }
}
```

The similar application can be done like this ([taken from here](https://ansaikuropedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%A0%83%E3%81%AB)):

[image: Every occurrence of Japanese letter な is red]

```
function make_every_letter_e_red () {
   for ( p of document.getElementsByTagName("p") ) {
      p.innerHTML = p.innerHTML.replaceAll("e", "<span class='red'>e</span>");
   }
}
```

Can it be archived with CSS itself?

Comment: Can CSS select single characters in arbitrary positions within an element's text content? No, it can not.

Comment: Specifying a different font for those character ranges might be possible though. So if you had a font that already shows those characters "larger", that might perhaps be an option. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range (only if you need them "larger", as the first example suggests; for a different text _color_, that won't work.)

Comment: Can you share more details, like the original markup?

Comment: @NicoHaase Here it is: https://lyrics.imicomweb.com/ (every kanji is large) and https://ansaikuropedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%B2%E3%81%90%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F%E9%A0%83%E3%81%AB (every "な" is red)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: Pleae add sample markup to your question, not a link to any external website. Keep all relevant information here